# Spring MVC Java Tutorial Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm following the tutorial given here:

```
http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/
```

After deployment to tomcat, it runs good then i get this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

type Exception report

message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1284)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:101)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:183)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.12 logs.
```

I have all my jar files imported into my eclipse project and all seems to be well with everything, I can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you it cannot find the class because it is not available in your application.

If you are using `Maven`, make sure you have the dependency for `jstl` artifact:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```